# Install Windows 10 designed drivers on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, drivers

My laptop is by default installed with Windows 10. I've tried to downgrade it to Windows 8, but the touchpad wasn't recognized and the screen brightness couldn't be changed due to Intel graphics driver. I did try downloading the drivers from Intel website (my Samsung laptop uses Intel hardware), but they only install in Windows 10, not in previous versions.

I'm interested in downgrading to Windows 7, however I can't simply install the official disk image as I'll have the same issue I had with Windows 8 (touchpad, graphics etc.). I found that someone made a custom version of Windows 7 to support actual drivers: [youtu.be](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mkaIu02_Na0). I could test whether that custom Windows 7 works, but I'm not sure how I could dual-boot with Windows 11 (my actual OS) and Windows 7. Does anyone know if Windows 10+ designed-drivers will work in that custom Windows 7?

Comment: Impossible to answer. You don't specify what drivers you want working and no one, but the author of that Youtube video, will know what that modified Windows 7 is capable of.

Comment: Windows 11 and Windows 7 will be tough considering Windows 7 does not support Secure Boot and Windows 11 requires it.

Comment: @Tonny I think the graphics driver is here: [intel.com](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/19344/intel-graphics-windows-dch-drivers.html). The touchpad one I don't remember... Sure, I'll try commenting in the video... thanks.

Comment: @Hydroperv-0x4000, the Intel link you posted isn't a direct driver download, but an installer to the drivers (and the installer is the one that probably fails to install on Windows 7, not the drivers themselves.) In order to try to install the drivers, you'd need to install typical Windows 7 and check in the Device Manager which drivers (the Hardware ID of the devices) are missing and try to find them.

Comment: @YisroelTech Makes sense. I've opened Device Manager and I couldn't find any hardware ID, but I found the driver has several associated DLL files. The driver name is Intel(R) UHD Graphics 610.

Comment: See something like what this person did https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Video-Display-and-Touch/Windows-7-VGA-drivers-Probook-450-G4/m-p/5981398/highlight/true#M146464 . Ultimatly I think that you should have Windows 7 installed and if something ask for help then with when you have all the details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows 10+ designed-drivers have no chance of working in Windows 7,
as the driver model has changed. The two versions are too far apart.

You will need to search for drivers for each of your devices that shows up
with a yellow warning icon in Device Manager.

Specifically for the Intel UHD Graphics 610,
Intel does not support Windows 7 for their Kaby Lake 7th generation CPUs,
which includes the Iris and HD Graphics that are built into the processors.
Upon attempting to install the graphics drivers on a Windows 7 machine
you will get the message
"The computer does not meet the minimum requirements".

This can be fixed by copying one line in the driver `.inf` file.

For information about this hack see
[Fix for Windows 7 drivers for Intel 7th gen HD graphics 620 610 615 630 Iris 640 650](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7w9JofZQkxI).

(Note however that Windows 7 is too old and is completely vulnerable
to attacks. I don't advise connecting it to the internet.)

Comment: "Windows 10+ designed-drivers have no chance of working in Windows 7" and then "This can be fixed..." It's either or (and the truth is as you detailed that it actually may work with some playing around.)

Comment: @YisroelTech: As I said, the poster will need to search for solution for each of his devices that won't work. Not all of them will be as easy as the UHD Graphics 610. Don't nitpick on semantics, please.

Comment: Not sure what the semantics here is. I was just pointing out that your first paragraph is an incorrect and unnecessary generalization that there is nothing possible to do.

Comment: @YisroelTech: Not so - the Intel installation has multiple drivers for multiple Windows versions. It won't install the Windows 10 drivers in Windows 7 because they won't work. Apparently it still contains the Windows 7 drivers and they were only disabled by a config change. My answer is still correct.

Comment: The video's comments indicate an older version of the graphics driver has to be downloaded. I found it, but the description says it's for Windows 8.1 or less, while the download's filename says win10 (Windows 10). I'm a bit confused, isn't it supposed to be for Windows 10? https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/19082/intel-hd-graphics-driver-for-windows-7-8-1-for-nuc6i3sy-nuc6i5sy.html

Comment: @Hydroperv-0x4000: This looks like a good driver to try. The included file `ReadMe.txt` has a list of drivers with basically every 64-bit Windows version since 7.